# javascript issue with inner looping

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to loop 3 Arrays and generate a group of children with unique IDs

But for some reason property `id` is not getting unique value (see the console results)

I tried various ways like used `forEach`, used `closures`, used local variables. none of them are working.

```js
const alpha = [{ name: 'AAA', value: 'a' }, { name: 'BBB', value: 'b' }, { name: 'CCC', value: 'c' }], 
 numeric = [{ name: 'ONE', value: '1' }, { name: 'TWO', value: '2' }, { name: 'THREE', value: '3' }], 
 symbol = [{ name: 'AT', value: '@' }, { name: 'HASH', value: '#' }, { name: 'DOLLAR', value: '$' }];

const result = alpha.map(a => {
  a.children = numeric.map(n => {
    n.children = symbol.map(s => {
      s.id = a.value + n.value + s.value;
      return s;
    });
    n.id = a.value + n.value;
    return n;
  });
  a.id = a.value;
  return a;
})


console.log(result[0].children[0].children[0].id)   // should be "a1@"
console.log(result[1].children[0].children[0].id)   // should be "b1@"
console.log(result[2].children[0].children[0].id)   // should be "c1@"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're modifying your input objects, so the same (for example) `s` is being modified multiple times.  This is why you're only seeing the last `alpha` and `numeric` in your IDs — they run last, so were the last to modify the shared object.

To fix this, return a *new* object with your ID, and all should be well:

```js
const alpha = [{ name: 'AAA', value: 'a' }, { name: 'BBB', value: 'b' }, { name: 'CCC', value: 'c' }], 
 numeric = [{ name: 'ONE', value: '1' }, { name: 'TWO', value: '2' }, { name: 'THREE', value: '3' }], 
 symbol = [{ name: 'AT', value: '@' }, { name: 'HASH', value: '#' }, { name: 'DOLLAR', value: '$' }];

const result = alpha.map(a => {
  a.children = numeric.map(n => {
    n.children = symbol.map(s => {
      return { ...s, id: a.value + n.value + s.value };
    });
    return { ...n, id: a.value + n.value };
  });
  return { ...a, id: a.value };
})


console.log(result[0].children[0].children[0].id)   // should be "a1@"
console.log(result[1].children[0].children[0].id)   // should be "b1@"
console.log(result[2].children[0].children[0].id)   // should be "c1@"
```

Comment: Perfect... I totally forgot that i was modifying the same object reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping over the array `symbols` many times, but each time you are getting references to the same objects:

```
symbol.map(s => {  // s is always a reference to the same set of objects object
   s.id = a.value + n.value + s.value;
   return s;
});
```

Each time you see one of these objects, you overwrite the `id` property on *the same object*, so of course when you log them they have the same id.

```js
const alpha = [{ name: 'AAA', value: 'a' }, { name: 'BBB', value: 'b' }, { name: 'CCC', value: 'c' }], 
 numeric = [{ name: 'ONE', value: '1' }, { name: 'TWO', value: '2' }, { name: 'THREE', value: '3' }], 
 symbol = [{ name: 'AT', value: '@' }, { name: 'HASH', value: '#' }, { name: 'DOLLAR', value: '$' }];

const result = alpha.map(a => {
  a.children = numeric.map(n => {
    n.children = symbol.map(s => {
      s.id = a.value + n.value + s.value;
      return s;
    });
    n.id = a.value + n.value;
    return n;
  });
  a.id = a.value;
  return a;
})

// these are the same objects:
console.log("0 & 1 Same reference?", result[0].children[0].children[0] === result[1].children[0].children[0])

console.log("1 & 2 Same reference?", result[1].children[0].children[0] === result[2].children[0].children[0])
```